# When is the DOM ready and how to enumerate its elements?

Tags: objective-c, macos, dom, webview

Using a Webview, I would like to find the links inside this page.

```
-(void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    DOMDocument *myDOMDocument = [[self.webview mainFrame] DOMDocument];
```

looks like a good starting point, but I find the WebScriptObject Class Reference a little cryptic. Clearly I don't want to evaluate some Javascript to get the links. I want to directly read the DOM.

How may I find which nodes in the DOM are links, and get the address they are pointing to ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the DOMNodes for images

see walkNodeTree @ http://cocoadev.com/wiki/DOMCore

-- complete sample to find image nodes, get their src and make nsimages

```
@implementation DDAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [self.webview.mainFrame loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dominik.pich.info/Home.html"]]];
}

-(void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    DOMDocument *myDOMDocument = [[self.webview mainFrame] DOMDocument];

    NSMutableArray *imgs = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self walkNodeTree:myDOMDocument imgsCollected:imgs];

    //bad code, demo
    NSMutableArray *nsImages = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (DOMNode *img in imgs) {
        for(int i = 0; i < img.attributes.length; i++) {
            DOMNode *attr = [img.attributes item:i];
            NSLog(@"%@", attr.nodeName);
            if([attr.nodeName.lowercaseString isEqualToString:@"src"]) {
                NSString *urlstring = [attr nodeValue];
                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstring relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dominik.pich.info/"]];
                NSImage *nsimg = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
                if(nsimg)
                    [nsImages addObject:nsimg];
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", nsImages);
}

- (void)walkNodeTree:(DOMNode*)parent imgsCollected:(NSMutableArray*)imgs {
    DOMNodeList *nodeList = [parent childNodes];
    unsigned i, length = [nodeList length];
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        DOMNode *node = [nodeList item:i];

        NSLog(@"%@", node.nodeName);
        if([node.nodeName.lowercaseString isEqualToString:@"img"]) {
            [imgs addObject:node];
        }
        else {
            //recurse
            [self walkNodeTree:node imgsCollected:imgs];
        }
    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the  [xpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) specification  [XPath Introduction](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_intro.asp)

By passing the HTML from an URL to [NSXMLDocument](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSXMLDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html&ei=E2FkUu7RFYrP0QXqn4GgAQ&usg=AFQjCNH_zCoDbl6-nwDywT4Uxi8PqbbMxg&bvm=bv.54934254,d.d2k) and then getting the values I want with [NSXMLNode's](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLNode_Class/Reference/Reference.html) [nodesForXPath:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLNode_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSXMLNode/nodesForXPath:error:)

In this case I use the mainframe's URL. But any valid URL should be ok.

Both NSXML classes seem to have no trouble parsing the html just as they do xml

There are plenty of xpath query string syntax examples you can search for and I found it is very easy to drill down into the DOM tree once you know what the HTML tag and class syntax is.

I have used a very simple **a href** query for the whole page here.

But I have included a commented out example to show a tiny bit more.

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [theWebView setFrameLoadDelegate:self];

    NSURL* fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];

    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];
     [[theWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
}

-(void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    NSError *err_p = nil;

    NSXMLDocument * xmlDoc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL   URLWithString:[theWebView mainFrameURL]]
                                                                  options:(NSXMLNodePreserveWhitespace|
                                                                           NSXMLNodePreserveCDATA)
                                                                    error:&err_p];

    if (xmlDoc == nil) {

        xmlDoc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL   URLWithString:[theWebView mainFrameURL]]
                                                      options:NSXMLDocumentTidyXML
                                                        error:&err_p];

    }

    NSError * error2;


      NSString *xpathQueryTRTest =@"//a";//--query string for all <a href tags
//--   for example 2 --NSString *xpathQueryTRTest =@"//div/p[1]";//--query string for all <a href tags
NSArray *newItemsNodesTRTEST = [xmlDoc nodesForXPath:xpathQueryTRTest error:&error2];//--xpath node results returned in an array

[xmlDoc release];

if (error2)
{
    [[NSAlert alertWithError:error2] runModal];
    return ;
}

for (NSXMLElement *node in newItemsNodesTRTEST)//--parse the nodes in the array
{

    NSLog(@"\nThe Node = %@\nThe node href value = %@", node, [[node attributeForName:@"href"]stringValue]);
    //--for example 2  --  NSLog(@"\nThe Node value = %@\n", [node stringValue]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[both](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13471616/766570) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19483933/766570) above are exclusive to MAC, rather than iOS. If you stumbled across this page looking for an iOS solution, check [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios) tutorial out, it basically uses the [hpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple) library for DOM node traversal. The rest is pretty straight forward.