# Where is the documentation for DOMNode, DOMNodeList and other Webkit data structures?

Tags: objective-c, macos, webkit

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471466/when-is-the-dom-ready-and-how-to-enumerate-its-elements) a while back  and the answer is using these data structures:  `DOMNode`, `DOMNodeList` , and a method `-childNodes:`.

The two data structures don't have documentation in the OS X documentation; the only interesting documentation I found was in the headers: `DomText.h`, inside the Webkit framework.

The `childNodes` gives some results, but I can't really tell if they are related to Webkit: `NSTreeNode`.

The code comes from: http://cocoadev.com/wiki/DOMCore

It seems that these data structures map to the DOM specification, but I don't like to reuse code that I could not rewrite myself from the documentation. It feels like voodoo programming.

So where should I start ? Is there a documentation for traversing the DOM in Objective-C ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DOMNode, DOMNodeList are classes from the webkit and listed in the:

[WebKit Objective-C Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/ObjC_Classic/_index.html)

The reference also has alink to:

[WebKit Objective-C Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/DisplayWebContent.html)

These links are on the internet. If you want to see them in the Xcode Documentation then just do a search for them using the title or the class.

You may also find [WebKit DOM Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/WebKitJavaScript.html) of use

----------Update

The links should give you an understanding of how to use the **DOM Objective-C API**

As quoted in the [Using the Document Object Model from Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/Tasks/DOMObjCBindings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001206-124858) section of **WebKit Objective-C Programming Guide**

> The Document Object Model API implements the Level 2 Document Object
>   Model (DOM) specification, developed by the World Wide Web Consortium.
>   This specification provides a platform and language-neutral interface
>   that allows programs and scripts to dynamically access and change the
>   content, structure and style of a document —usually HTML or XML—by
>   providing a structured set of objects that correspond to the
>   document’s elements.
>
> The intention of the DOM Objective-C API is to conform to—as close as
>   technically possible—the W3C DOM specification. Therefore, standard
>   Cocoa conventions such as method naming, argument titling, and
>   exception handling may not be reflected in this API. Following a few
>   conventions discussed in this article, you can derive the DOM
>   Objective-C API from the specification. This article also discusses
>   the differences between the DOM specification and DOM Objective-C API.

From [w3 org](http://www.w3.org) you can also look at:

[Level 2 DOM Objects](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/CR-DOM-Level-2-20000510/object-index.html)

[Level 2 DOM specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/CR-DOM-Level-2-20000510/)

[XML DOM Introduction](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_intro.asp)  from [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com)

Comment: This doesn't help. DOMNode had no real documentation. It feels like you have to learn how to use the Objective-c object by looking at the header and the DOM specification.

Comment: From what I understand. You need to have an idea of the DOM works. And how the Objective -c DOM API can access the DOM. See my update

Comment: So basically, in the WebKit documentation shipped with XCode, we have absolutely nothing about these classes. Everything is in the IDL files on w3c.org.

Comment: I am new to it as you. But what I think is going on is There is the existing DOM specification. Apple has just implemented some APIs to use them. And is only explaining how to use them within those Objective -C APIs. But the specifics are the same. To confuse you more  Do a search for  NXMLDocument, NSXMLNode

Comment: Sad but true. And in WebKit 2 with WK classes they leave you to use JavaScript.